# How to write insert query with case when?

Tags: sql

Is it possible to write insert query that conditionally insert values into column

Here is my query that I have tried:

```
insert into table_1 (status, MF, AF, MED, Year)
values ('Y', 'Y', 'N', CASE WHEN MF = 'Y' THEN GETDATE() ELSE NULL END, 2017)
```

Comment: Yes, but conditions on what? `MF = 'Y'` of what record?

Comment: MF is a column name when it is Y for year 2017 then only MED should get inserted with today's date

Comment: But you are inserting `MF` your self, why not do it your self?

Comment: You can do an update instead, `UPDATE table_1 set MED = getdate() where MF = 'Y'`

Comment: Yeah, I can update it but i want to make it in single query while inserting only. Is it posible?

Comment: I don't understand what you want, is this the full query you are using? what are you trying to insert?! This is not logical at all! just type the date/null your self if its a single record.

Comment: Its not single record. I think it is not possible to do so in single query..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Sql Server`:

```
DECLARE @Status VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @MF VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @AF VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @MED DATETIME
DECLARE @YEAR INT

SET @Status = 'Y'
SET @MF = 'Y'
SET @AF = 'N'
SET @YEAR = 2017

INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME
    (status, MF, AF, MED, Year)
 VALUES (@Status, @MF, @AF, CASE WHEN @MF = 'Y' THEN GETDATE() ELSE NULL END, @YEAR)
```